# Get location of a file pointer

Tags: c++, c, file, winapi

In Windows, is there no way to get the current location of a file pointer?

For example, if I use `SetFilePointer`, and I want to determine whereabouts in the file the file pointer wound up after the seek?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return value of that function tells you the new position. Quoting [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx):

> If the function succeeds and lpDistanceToMoveHigh is NULL, the return
>   value is the low-order DWORD of the new file pointer.
>
> **Note**  If the function returns a value other than
>   INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER, the call to SetFilePointer has succeeded.
>   You do not need to call GetLastError.
>
> If function succeeds and lpDistanceToMoveHigh is not NULL, the return
>   value is the low-order DWORD of the new file pointer and
>   lpDistanceToMoveHigh contains the high order DWORD of the new file
>   pointer.

If you want to discover the current location *without* moving it, then pass a "move method" of `FILE_CURRENT` and a distance of zero.

The documentation also contains an example of how to wrap that function into one that doesn't require splitting the upper and lower portions of the position into separate variables.

Comment: ...I read the documentation on that a good 5 times and didn't even see that.  Thank-you sir, I'm going to go get some coffee...

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
high_dword = 0;

low_dword = SetFilePointer(file, 0, &high_dword, FILE_CURRENT);

pos = high_dword << 32 | low_dword
```

Answer (score 2):

`SetFilePointer` returns the new file pointer, but only works for file offsets < 4GB.  If you want to handle larger files use `SetFilePointerEx`.

If you just want to retrieve the current position use FILE_CURRENT with an offset of zero.